# how many ways we can select a team of $5$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are $20$ A players and $6$ B Players, in how many ways a team of $5$ which includes at least $2$ Player A and at least $2$ Player B exists?

I found out it will be $ C_{20}^{2}\cdot C_{6}^{3}+C_{20}^{3}\cdot C_{6}^{2} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The team of five can be made up as the following....

$A, 2, 3$

$B, 3, 2$

The number of ways is therefore

$$\binom{20}{2}\cdot \binom{6}{3}+\binom{20}{3}\cdot\binom{6}{2}= 20900$$

Comment: how can 3rd case exist there must be at least 2 B players but you took 1?

Comment: @JKLM If that's the case then you need to clarify the question. It should be 2 player A and 2 player B and not 2 player A and player B.

Comment: I'm sorry I have updated the question and I guess my answer is right?

Comment: Yes, except the larger number goes on top for the correct combination format $C^{20}_2$.